# App Store Review "3. 2.0 Business: Other Business Model Issues" | App already online in the App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I am a developer for a University and developed a "Class Record Book" app for teachers to register the presence of students and content of the classes.

I sent the app to App Store for review and it was accepted, then I made some releases to fix some bugs and add new features, all fine. But now Apple stopped to accept my submits stating the following reason for rejection:

```
Guideline 3.2 - Business


During our review, we found that this app was designed for a specific business or organization, including its partners, clients or employees, and not for general distribution on the App Store. Business apps available on the App Store are meant for use by a wide variety of external customers around the world.

As this app is not intended for general distribution, it cannot be made available on the App Store. We encourage you to review the other ways to distribute your business app and choose one that better meets your business needs.

If you revise your app concept and features to provide substantial value to a wide variety of external customers around the world, we recommend that you also review our App Store Review Guidelines, including, among others, guidelines 2.5.4 - Background Location, 3.2.2 - Unacceptable Business Models, 4.0 - Design, 4.2 - Minimum Functionality, and 4.3 - Spam, prior to resubmitting the app for general distribution on the App Store.
```

I would like to continue having my app on the public App Store and not distribute it as private.
I found some similar apps on the App Store that are currently online and asked for this in the Resolution Center. But I still get rejected, that's my Resolution Center:

```
From Apple
3. 2.0 Business: Other Business Model Issues
Hello,

Thank you for providing this information.

Regarding 3.2.0, as this app is not intended for general distribution, it cannot be made available on the App Store. We encourage you to review the other ways to distribute your business app and choose one that better meets your business needs.

We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app.

Best regards,

App Store Review


May 18, 2020 at 3:37 PM
From troyackapple@ugb.edu.br (Fundacao Educacional Rosemar Pimentel)
Our App is similar to at least two other Apps that are currently online, namely:
- "eCampus Professor" "Portal eCampus da UFAM" created by "Universidade Federal do Amazonas" found at: https://apps.apple.com/br/app/ecampus-professor/id1407534419
- "Estácio Docente" created by "Estácio" found at https://apps.apple.com/br/app/est%C3%A1cio-docente/id1482191115
We would like to know which criteria made our App unacceptable, considering our app is about the same while still allowing the two apps mentioned previously.

We are waiting for your reply so thtat we can get our update published as soon as possible.

Thank you.
```

I don't want to distribute the app as private since the devices are not owned by the organization. Distributing privately would cause dificults for teachers to find the app since we will have to send redemption codes or links to download the app. Otherwise the public App Store is perfect for us, it's easy.

The app: https://apps.apple.com/br/app/di%C3%A1rio-ugb/id1494945410

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you submitting the app as an individual developer or under the universities organization developer program?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thank you! In my membership details [membership](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership) says that my Program Type is "
Apple Developer Program" and my Entity Type is "Company / Organization"

Comment: I submitted the app as an Organization, not as individual.

Comment: Is the organization/company affiliated/authorised by the university to publish such an app? Is the company a privately owned or is ti affiliated to the university?

Comment: The organization/company is the university itself.

Comment: Try contacting the App Store Review team or Apple developer support and query them about what exactly they think is causing the violation. They should be happy to assist you.